# Error in setting ClearCase dynamic view

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Error encountered while setting a ClearCase dynamic view.

```
root@clearcase:~ # ct setview cc_dyn_view
ct: Error: Operation "view_ws_is_ws_view" failed: view storage directory or control files unavailable --
additional information may be present in the view server host's view log.
root@kviewsrvr:~ #
```

View log shows:-

```
2013-11-20T11:40:21+05:30 view_server(16910): Error: Operation fcntl(F_SETLK), .pid: Input/output error
2013-11-20T11:40:21+05:30 view_server(16910): Warning: Temporary server starting for unusable view at '/net/clearcase/viewstore/root/cc_dyn_view.vws'
```

Anyone please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the ClearCase version, and on the view and vob server (Unix, Solaris, windows).

[This thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013807298) reports a similar error, sugesting a Linux system limitation:

> The size of the file table will need to be increased.
>   Increase the '`nflocks`' kernel parameter from 200 to 400.

If it is not that, you need to check:

- the server ClearCase logs (not just the view logs),
- any permission issue in accessing `/net/clearcase/viewstore/root/cc_dyn_view.vws`.